# Configuring the WebClient Spring boot 3 - spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I migrate my batch project in spring boot 2.7.X to spring boot 3.2.0 and i have a problem to migrate this part of my code :

```
  @Bean
  @SuppressWarnings("all")
  public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository client) {
    var oauth =
        new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            client, new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("myAuthProvider");
    //...java code
}
```

I have an error :
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository
location: package org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server

Which java class i must use instead of UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository to make my code work

Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.0-M1/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/server/UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.html) `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` is deprecated/removed.

You have to use `AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` instead.

More details you will get from documentation [AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/6.0.0-M1/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.html).